# Lotus domino xpages global objects for server side javascript not showing

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to figure out why my global object selection is no longer available when I am using server side javascript.  Also my data sources are blank when looking at the side panel on right but the xpage does have a data source assigned.  If I removed the data source from the panel and re-add the data source, then my data source shows correctly(with all the fields available).
This just started happening recently.  I am running 9.0.1 FP10 SHF380.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: This is not a complete answer but I did find out if I close the designer perspective and open it back up, then the global object selection will appear back in the drop down.  My data source remains blank.  I have a feeling this may be a feature of the version I am using.

Comment: Watch for which panel you are currently in.  The replicate command, for example, does not work unless your cursor is in the page panel.  The same may be true when looking at the data source panel.

Comment: Try to work (sometimes) from the Source tab, and click the object you want to change, e.g. the xp:view line when you want to see the global elements, etc. By the way, you're 2 releases behind...